# Program type already present: com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClient$1

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Unity 2018.4.15. Build project for Android platform with error:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  J:\Program
>   Files\2018.4.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe
>   -classpath "J:\Program Files\2018.4.15f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar"
>   org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
>   "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[ D8: Program type already present:
>   com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClient$1
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease'.

There is only one lib with name "installreferrer-1.0.aar" in Assets/Plugins/Android/ folder. I use Facebook plugin (7.18.0), GoogleMobileAds (4.2.1), Applovin SDK (9.11.1) with Facebook mediation (5.6.1.0).

If I deleted installreferrer-1.0.aar - project compile ok, but it crashes after running on device. If I rollback library & delete the Facebook plugin the project compiles ok, but crashes as well. I think that FB connect is causing my error, but I cannot resolve it.

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
               android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb2575328535843348" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled" android:value="true" />
    <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider2575328535843348" android:exported="true" />
    <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</manifest>
```

mainTeplate.gradle

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
**BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each {
    ext {
        it.setProperty("android.useAndroidX", true)
        it.setProperty("android.enableJetifier", true)
    }
}
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com/" // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
        }
        maven {
            url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/AdColony/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
        }
        maven {
            url "https://applovin.bintray.com/Android-Adapter-SDKs" // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Fyber/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8, Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/IronSource/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
        }
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/smaato-sdk-releases/" // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Smaato/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Facebook/Editor/Dependencies.xml:10
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.+' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Facebook/Editor/Dependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' // Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.addSupportLibraryDependency
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:adcolony-adapter:4.1.2.1' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/AdColony/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:facebook-adapter:[5.6.1.0]' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Facebook/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:fyber-adapter:7.5.0.0' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Fyber/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:google-adapter:[17.2.1.7]' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Google/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:ironsource-adapter:6.13.0.1.0' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/IronSource/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:mintegral-adapter:10.1.51.2' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Mintegral/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:smaato-adapter:21.3.1.0' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Smaato/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:tapjoy-adapter:12.4.0.0' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/Tapjoy/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.applovin.mediation:unityads-adapter:3.4.0.1' // Assets/MaxSdk/Mediation/UnityAds/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:9.11.1' // Assets/MaxSdk/AppLovin/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[5,6)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5,6)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[16.0.0]' // Assets/MaxSdk/AppLovin/Editor/Dependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0' // Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml:4
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        applicationId '**APPLICATIONID**'
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "16g"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'**STREAMING_ASSETS**]
    }**SIGN**

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_DEBUG**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_DEBUG**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled **MINIFY_RELEASE**
            useProguard **PROGUARD_RELEASE**
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD****SIGNCONFIG**
        }
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS****SPLITS**
**BUILT_APK_LOCATION**
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }
}**SPLITS_VERSION_CODE****REPOSITORIES****SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Facebook android dependencies from "[5,6)" to "5.13.0". This was included into your mainTemplate.gradle from file
 `Assets/FacebookSDK/Plugins/Editor/Dependencies.xml`

Comment: Hm, error changed to: D8: Program type already present: android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback

Comment: I found solve: Make change version "[5,6)" to "5.13.0" AND(!!!)  Assets -> GooglePlayResolver -> Android Resolver -> Settings -> Set Jetiffier On
Force Resolve.  Thank you!!

Comment: Hmm... compile, but crash on device =(

Answer (score 1):

Resolve problem:

1. Remove FB plugin, FB Mediation from project and manifest
2. Exit from Unity
3. Remove Library folder
4. Launch Unity and compile without FB!
5. Install FB
6. Change your Facebook android dependencies from "[5,6)" to "5.13.0"
7. Assets -> GooglePlayResolver -> Android Resolver -> Settings -> Force Resolve
8. Profit!